# Which is the better .NET ORM Tool: SubSonic or WebWidgetry?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, orm

I was pointed to SubSonic (www.subsonicproject.com), but then I found WebWidgetry (www.nthpenguin.com)  Before I dig into them too much I'm curious to know who's used either and what the pro's and con's might be?

Thanks for the help,
Jim

Answer (score 4):

I have used SubSonic once before and it was incredibly easy to setup and use.  I was actually quite impressed, and for ORM tools it takes a lot to impress me.

Answer (score 0):

WebWidgetry, seems to be in a release candidate while subsonic is a fairly well known ORM mapper.

WW also seems to be going for a totally different market. 
Subsonic is a general purpose ORM which is modelled to be fast and easy to use.

My basic advice if you want to use anything in production wait till it's got sufficient testing / community behind it.

RC releases are usually not the best thing when it comes to quality and support might be lacking.